# Serve Minified Files after Angular CLI --Prod

Tags: javascript, angular

I have minified my simple angular app using the Angular CLI's command, it has created a dist folder with the project folder and the minified files. Yet when I run ng serve, regardless if it is in the root or in the dist/projectName it will server the unminified, development files.

I would just like to test whether the production version actually works and can be served. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: just open the `index.html` from the dist folder in your browser

Comment: Building an angular app creates js files to be hosted on a server. Serving an angular application makes a "phantom build" and allows you to preview your application in your browser. Those are two distinct things.

Comment: Just reading through the [Angular deployment guide](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) you can use `ng build --prod` to build for a production build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, the minified files in the dist folder are created only for the deployment basis meaning that you can execute this code directly by opening the index.html file and your application will work normally.

On the other hand, if you run `ng serve`, it'll definitely take the unminified files in the application irrespective of the minification.

As I see it you can check whether Production environment works in the below manner:

Execute the command `ng build --prod`. This will build all the minified files in the dist folder. Then goto the dist folder and open the index.html in the browser without executing `ng serve`. This will load the production version of your application.

One alternate solution that I can think of is you can also try serving using the command `ng serve --prod`. I have not tried this approach as I follow the previous one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways for you:

**1)** self host the application using IIS or similar, Just point the path to the dist folder, there is a nice tutorial [here](https://medium.com/m/global-identity?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.angularindepth.com%2Fdeploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7).

**2)** open the `index.html` file created by the ng-build --prod command and test it.

***REMEMBER***

ng-serve will not minifie your files whatsoever, it will serve the uncompressed files as it and create a local port (4200) for you to run your application, but it will never compress or minifie the files for you.

The only way to properly minifie the files is using `ng-build --prod --build-optimizer`

Answer (score 0):

As one comment explains open the `index.html` within the `dist` folder.
But I recommend doing this using a webserver if there are asynchronous calls.

While `ng serve` is serving files for a development optimized environment `ng build --prod` performs a lot optimisations which are too expensive in the development stage.